# How to setup organization 2FA login on company github account allow personal github login

Tags: github

I am thinking to set a github organization account for business. Then let employee to login with their personal github account. When an employee join the business, I need to add his personal github on the organzation account. If one left the company, I have to remove it from github. I am looking for a better solution.

The business has setup gmail for every employee. Everyone who left the company, their gmail account will be disabled. So I am thinking how to link people's personal github with their company gmail account.

I see 2FA may be a solution but I found all articles mention `Single sign on`. but it is only available on github enterprise member which is very expensive.

Are there anything available to use from `Team` plan?

Answer (score 1):

For automatic onboarding and offboarding you need to have the enterprise plan, there is no support in the team plan. With it you can configure an Identity Provider (IdP) such as Okta or Azure Active Directory.

With the IdP configured your users will be prompted to verify their personal account has access by also logging on to your IdP provider.

GitHub user a number of standardized protocols to enable this scenario.

- Single Sign On via SAML (SSO)
- Automatic user provisioning via SKIM
- Automatic team provisioning via Team Sync

Alternatively you can setup a Enterprise Managed Users GitHub Enterprise organization. In that case your GitHub account will be linked to the identity provider and it will automatically provirion users in your GitHub organization. These users sign in with their EMU account and won't need to use their personal GitHub ID at all, they do all of their work through their enterprise user.

Comment: I think IdP is what I am looking for. but enterprise cost $231 per user which is very expensive. Is there any word around to use Team plan?

Comment: There must be some features that set apart the cheaper teams from the more expensive enterprise.

Comment: exactly. that's what I am looking for. Their doc doesn't give much information on that.

Comment: So yeah, you'll need enterprise for that.